# Bra-Ket Notation vs Wavefunction Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, notation

We know that the rule for creating excited states for a Quantum Harmonic Oscillator is $|n\rangle=\frac{(a^\dagger)^n(|0\rangle)}{\sqrt{n!}}$. I wanted to derive from this the familiar rule in terms of wavefunctions, $\psi_{n}=\frac{(a^\dagger)^n(\psi_{0})}{\sqrt{n!}}$. I tried applying $\langle x|$ on both sides of the former equation, which gives $\langle x|n\rangle=\frac{\langle x|(a^\dagger)^n|0\rangle}{\sqrt{n!}}$. The LHS gives me $\psi_{n}$, but how to deal with the RHS? We know that $\langle x|(a^\dagger)^n=a^n\langle x|$, so this means that
$\psi_{n}=\frac{(a)^n(\psi_{0})}{\sqrt{n!}}$ which is not correct. Could someone explain what is wrong with this method, and how can we perform this derivation correctly?

Comment: I believe you are having essentially the same issue as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380091/) question, although dressed up a bit differently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the two different solution approaches of the quantum harmonic oscillator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/614983/)