# Can I replace eigenvalue of $p$ operator with position space representation of $p$ operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle x|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle &= \int dp\ \langle x|\hat{p}|p\rangle \langle p|\psi\rangle\\
&=\int dp\ p\langle x|p\rangle \langle p|\psi\rangle \\
&=\int dp \ \left(-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \langle x|p\rangle \langle p|\psi\rangle
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Please explain how we can go from second step to third step? In the second step, the $p$ is an eigenvalue which has been replaced by position representation of the momentum operator in the third step. How can we replace a number by an operator?

Comment: You don't go from the second line to the third. You go from the first to the second, and, *independently* from the first to the third, using [standard rules](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76299/how-does-the-momentum-operator-act-on-state-kets/76317#76317) .

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The object $\langle \boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol p\rangle$ is proportional to $\mathrm e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\boldsymbol x\cdot\boldsymbol p}$, and therefore it satisfies the PDE
$$
\boldsymbol p\,\langle \boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol p\rangle=-i\hbar\,\partial_{\boldsymbol x} \langle \boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol p\rangle
$$

Alternatively, and as noted by C. Zachos, you may let $\hat{\boldsymbol p}$ act to the left instead of letting it act on the right:
$$
 \left(-i\hbar \partial_{\boldsymbol x} \langle \boldsymbol x|\right)|\boldsymbol p\rangle\overset{\mathrm{left}}= \langle\boldsymbol x|\hat{\boldsymbol p}|\boldsymbol p\rangle\overset{\mathrm{right}}=\boldsymbol p\, \langle\boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol p\rangle
$$

We get the same result, naturally; this is of course no coincidence. We leave it to the reader to reflect on this fact.