# Does this notation for the momentum in quantum mechanics make sense?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, hilbert-space, notation

Let $P$ be the momentum operator. Susskind writes:

$$P |\Psi \rangle =-ih \frac d {dx} |\Psi \rangle$$
Then he states that this can be rewritten as
$$-ih\frac {d \psi(x)}{dx}$$
Where $\psi(x)$ is the wave function belonging to $|\Psi\rangle$

**It seems to me that the first equation is meaningless.** **How can we differentiate a state (a ket) w.r.t. $x$**? (as opposed to the representation of that state in a wave function, as in the second equation).

- Am I correct that this notation $\frac d {dx} |\Psi \rangle$ is hacky?
- If yes, how do we correctly write down the definition of the momentum operator in terms of the ket $|\Psi \rangle$? (i.e. without choosing a basis, and thus without using a wave function)

Comment: Why do people read Susskind's books/watch his lectures? They are not good...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, why do you think they are not good? I have learnt a lot about QM in just 3 days.

Comment: If you learnt a lot of QM in just 3 days from Susskind, imagine how much you would have learnt if you used a good source!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation

Comment: @KyleKanos, that wikipedia article only contains the momentum as an operator on the wave function, not on the ket.

Comment: @Programmer2134 read more of the subsection on Spinless position space wavefunction.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I could never really get through his lectures.  I know they're not designed for a "real" class, but to me they come off as having a folksy, almost forced unsophistication which tends to obscure the actual content.  Not to downplay his knowledge and contributions to physics, but it's just not my style.

Comment: Indeed, Susskind's stretch is meaningless, strictly speaking, but it can be easily salvaged by hitting it with [an x-bra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76317/66086).