# Derive $\langle p|\hat x=i\hbar {\partial_p}\langle p|$ from $[\hat x,F(\hat p)]=i\hbar \partial_{\hat p} F(\hat p) $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, commutator

Suppose that $p=-i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ was known, i.e. $\langle x|p=-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x|$. 
Suppose the only other known condition was     $[x,F(p)]=i\hbar \frac{\partial F(p)}{\partial p}$.(which could be derived from the previous one. )

Then how to derive $\langle p|x=i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\langle p|$ directly?

I tried to complete $\langle p|$ into an operator by $|m\rangle\langle p|$ then apply the commutation relationship $[x,|z\rangle\langle p|]
=-i\hbar \frac{\partial |z\rangle\langle p|}{\partial p}$. However, after expanding it, I was not able to get rid of a term $-|z\rangle\langle p|x$, which indicated something wrong.

Is there anyway to derive $\langle p|x=i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\langle p|$   from   $[x,F(p)]=i\hbar \frac{\partial F(p)}{\partial p}$?

Comment: What makes you think that what you are trying to prove is correct? More precisely the RHS is ill-defined.

Comment: Can't you get from $\langle x | \hat{p} | \psi\rangle = -i\hbar \partial_x \langle x | \psi \rangle$ the form of the eigenfunctions of $\hat{p}$ as plane waves? and then what you are looking for can be just derived by integration by parts?

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/172089/66086).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
\langle  p|\hat x |x\rangle = x \langle  p |x\rangle =x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar }} e^{-ipx/\hbar}=i\hbar \partial_p e^{-ipx/\hbar}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar }}= i\hbar \partial_p \langle  p |x\rangle ,
$$
and note it holds for all *x*.

Can you now sandwich the above between $  | p \rangle $ and $\langle x|  $  and integrate over *x* and *p* to get the more memorable 
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\hat x= \int \!\! dp ~~|p\rangle ~i\hbar \partial_p \langle p |  } ~~~~~~~?
$$

Comment: Got it. (I got really messed up by not realizing those $x$ and $p$ s were no longer operators after a long night.) But still, It troubles me why we need all those fourier relationships and integral identities, I felt like we should able to derive the expression directly from $[x,F(x)]$, where $[p, F(x)]$ was obvious. It seemed to me that the duality has already been fully characterized, so why can't we just go pass the integral, and get a purly differential solution?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd equation says effectively that, in the momentum space representation, $\hat x $ presents as $i\hbar \partial_p$, so $[i\hbar \partial_p , F(p)]= i\hbar \partial_p F(p)$.