# Representation of $|l, m\rangle$ states in spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum, wavefunction

I am currently working on Angular Momentum part of Gasiorowicz's QM.
The writer says that

\begin{align}
L_z |l, m\rangle &= \hbar m|l, m\rangle \\
\Rightarrow \langle\theta,\phi|L_z|l, m\rangle&=\hbar m\langle\theta,\phi|l, m\rangle \\
L_z &=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \\
\Rightarrow \langle\theta,\phi|L_z|l, m\rangle&= \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\langle\theta,\phi|l, m\rangle
\end{align}
The first two equality is easily understood but I don't understand why $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ can just move to the left of $ \langle\theta,\phi|$ though they were originally in the center.

Comment: Related: [How does the momentum operator act on state kets?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76299/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you. That post is almost exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $L_z$ is the generator of infinitesimal rotation about $z$-axis, Thus
$$\langle r,\theta,\phi|\left[1-i\left(\frac{\delta \phi}{\hbar}\right)L_z\right]|lm\rangle =\langle r,\theta,\phi-\delta \phi|lm\rangle $$
$$=\langle r,\theta,\phi|lm\rangle -\delta \phi\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\langle r,\theta,\phi|lm\rangle $$
$$\langle r,\theta ,\phi|L_z|lm\rangle =-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\langle r,\theta,\phi|lm\rangle $$

---

Note that:
$$L_z=-i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial\phi}\ \ \ \text{Abuse of notation}$$
$$L_z\rightarrow -i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial\phi}\ \ \ \ \  \ \ \text{In Position basis}$$

Comment: Ahh okay. So, the state where $|lm\rangle$ is rotated by $\delta \phi$ is $\left[1-i\left(\frac{\delta \phi}{\hbar}\right)L_z\right]|lm\rangle$. Hence in coordinate space, that state is the same as $\langle r,\theta,\phi-\delta \phi|lm\rangle$, if viewed as something like 'projection to the coordinate space'. Thank you.